# Unexpected behavior of datetick in octave

Tags: plot, octave

The following code should display data from `startDate=datenum('2016-01-01');` to `endDate=datenum('2016-12-31');`:

```
data=[ 7.3633e+05,     3460.4;
  7.3635e+05,     3119.7;
   7.364e+05,     2777.9;
  7.3642e+05,     2202.6;
  7.3649e+05,     569.57;
  7.3656e+05,      403.1;
  7.3658e+05,      789.5;
  7.3664e+05,     2242.1;
  7.3668e+05,     3120.6 ]

startDate=datenum('2016-01-01');
endDate=datenum('2016-12-31');

xData = linspace(startDate,endDate,12)
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2));

ax = gca;
set (ax, 'xtick',xData);
datetick (29, 'x');
```

but the `datetick` seems to ignore the values in `xData` as can be seen in the figure below. In my opinion it should display dates in the range 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31.
[image: datetick problem]

Comment: If this is an Octave-specific plotting issue, why the [tag:matlab] tag? If MATLAB is any indication, the inputs to `datetick` should come in a different order, e.g. `datetick ('x',29);` - your option gives me an error.

Comment: Because datetick should be compatible in my opinion. As you are noted correctly: matlab throws an error. octave not, although its behavior is a bit misleading.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you've switched the first two inputs of `datetick`. As you have it written, Octave will read the first input, `29`, and use this as the format (as you expect); however, any trailing inputs *after the format specification* are used to [indicate the start date to use](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/57e82b74f89b/scripts/plot/appearance/datetick.m#l140) (rather than relying on the tick values themselves). This seems to be intentionally [undocumented behavior](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/57e82b74f89b/scripts/plot/appearance/datetick.m#l138).

```
datestr(double('x'), 29)
%   0000-04-29
```

To get the expected behavior, [you need to flip the order of the two inputs](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/datetick.html) as the the axis specification (the `'x'`) should come first.

```
datetick('x', 29)
```

[image]

Also, if you want to specify exactly where the xticks are going to be, you'll want to use the `"keepticks"` option.

```
datetick('x', 29, 'keepticks')
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks! But isn't the documentation wrong? In "Example 2" it says: `datetick (2, 'x', 'keepticks');`

Comment: @derhelge Yes that appears to be a bug in the documentation. I have posted a bug report [here](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?49954)

Comment: Great! :) Thanks again